# How can B and *B both return the same address in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I saw this and I have a lot of doubts in my mind now:

```
 address  |   400   |   404   |   408   |   412   |   416   |   420   |
|---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------|
| value   |    2    |    3    |    6    |    4    |    5    |    8    |
| ref     | B[0][0] |         |         | B[1][0] |         | B[1][2] |
| ref     |         |  B[0]   |         |         |  B[1]   |         |

int B[2][3];

// B[0] and B[1] are one dimensional arrays of 3 integers

int (*P)[3] = B;
Print B;         \\ -> 400
Print &B[0];     \\ -> 400
Print *B;        \\ -> 400
Print B[0];      \\ -> 400
Print &B[0][0];  \\ -> 400
Print B + 1;     \\ -> 412
Print &B[1];     \\ -> 412
Print *(B+1);    \\ -> 412
Print B[1];      \\ -> 412
Print &B[1][0];  \\ -> 412
Print *(B+1)+2;  \\ -> 420
Print B[1]+2;    \\ -> 420
Print &B[1][2];  \\ -> 420
```

Q)How can B and *B both can return the address?
Can we increment array address B+1? Isn't this wrong?

Q)The *(B+1) or B[ 1 ] or &B[ 1 ][0] is equal to 412?
 I thought it would be 4.

Comment: actually this is a video on youtube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sHcnvZA2u88&list=PL2_aWCzGMAwLZp6LMUKI3cc7pgGsasm2_&index=10

Comment: In C, `X[Y]` is exactly the same as `*(X + Y)`. And `&*X` is the same as `X`.

Comment: Think about the types: `B` is of type `int[2][3]`, and `B[1]` is of type `int[3]` (so its value must be an address), and `B[1][0]` (which has the value 4) is of type `int`.

Comment: @jlhonora I think there is some debate about whether `&*X` is the same as `X`, if `X` is not dereferencable (e.g. if it's a null pointer)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: If there's a debate, it should be a very short one. [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.5.3.2p3: "If the operand [of unary **`&`**] is the result of a unary **`*`** operator, neither that operator nor the **`&`** operator is evaluated and the result is as if both were omitted, except that the constraints on the operators still apply and the result is not an lvalue."

Comment: @MattMcNabb true! Thanks for clearing that up...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)

> How can B and *B both can return the address? Can we increment array
>   address B+1 isn't this wrong

Arrays decay into pointers to the first element at every opportunity therefore when you go to print `B`, it becomes `&B[0]` or the address of the first element of B (not `*B` as you say, this is the value at the first element).

2)

> The *(B+1) or B[ 1 ] or &B[ 1 ][0] is equal to 412 ? I thought it
>   would be 4.

B can be for this purpose thought of as an array of int arrays. Remember as before arrays decay to pointers at every opportunity and thus `*(B+1)` is the value of the first element (0'th element) of the second ([1]) "array" in B. Equivalently, B[1] is the same. `*B[1][0]` is a mixture of the first two. Again, all of these are the values at [1][0] in the array, which is an array of integers, not chars. The integer at this position is evidently 412. If this was a `char**` and the element was "412" however, then you would be right in saying the first element was '4'.

Comment: `...it becomes &B...` - nitpick; it becomes `&B[0]`.  `&B` is of the type `int (*)[2][3]`.

Comment: Fixed. Suppose it should be as correct as possible.

Comment: "at every opportunity" It doesn't do it in all contexts.

Comment: @Quiliom sir i have few doubts. I want to clear them. Can you create a chat place for us here....comments would go to long...what time is it comfortable for you to come online?

Comment: Related to you answer only

Answer (score 4):

> How can B and *B both can return the address

The first element of an array starts at the same address as the array itself.  (In other words, there is no initial padding).  So `&B`, `&B[0]`, `&B[0][0]` all indicate the same address , although they have different type.

After array-to-pointer decay, `B` means `&B[0]`, and `*B` means `&B[0][0]`.

> &B[ 1 ][0] is equal to 412 ? I thought it would be 4. ﻿

In this hypothetical example the addresses start from 400. The address of a memory location is different to the value stored in that location (which would be `4`).

> Can we increment array address B+1

In C, *increment* normally means the `++` operator. You can't write `B++`. But you can do `B+1`. Since `B` is an array, it decays to a pointer `&B[0]`, and you can add integers to pointers.

Perhaps you are overlooking the meaning of array syntax;  in general `*(p+N)` is identical to `p[N]`.

There are corner cases where `*p` and `*(p+0)` are different but those cases don't affect this example; `*B` means the same as `B[0]`.

Comment: when does this array to pointer decay happen? I have never read this in any book not even in K&R. What i have read is *b always return the value what pointer is pointing to

Comment: can you give me an example as you said in some cases *p & *(p+0) might be different? Please edit you answer for these two questions of mine

Comment: Array-to-pointer decay is lvalue-to-rvalue conversion when happening on an array. It happens anytime you mention the name of an array except for as the operand of unary `&` or `sizeof`. The effect is that you get an rvalue which is a pointer to the first element of the array (so, `a` gives the same thing as `&a[0]`, if `a` is an array).   `*b` is an lvalue which designates a memory location; whether or not you actually retrieve the value stored in that location (i.e. whether you do lvalue-to-rvalue conversion) depends on the rest of the expression. (Eg. `*b = 5;` does not retrieve the value)

Comment: It is often not mentioned in books, either because the author doesn't actually understand it, or the author understands it so well that they don't realize that the reader may need further explanation.

Comment: If `p` is a null pointer then `&*p` is OK but `&*(p+0)` is not . There might be others, I don't recall right now